# How do I make this function read the string with getline and behave the same with an int?

Tags: c++, string, templates, overloading, getline

```
template<typename T>
T get(const string &prompt)
{
    cout<<prompt;
    T ret;
    cin>>ret;
    return ret;
}
```

I don't know how to do this with overloading; basically, this works with any type of data, right...

I tried with `typeid(variable).name();` and got the output of a string variable and tried to make an if inside the get function. However it did not work.

Comment: Of course you cannot **overload** it because the parameter's type and number shouldn't be changed. So my advise is that though specifying a function isn't a good idea, but here it seems if you want to do some different work on `string`, you should do it.

Comment: @Constructor "specifying a function isn't a good idea"  what does that even mean? Please use the answer field for answers ;)

Comment: @user463035818 Well, others has already help me done it, I'm lazy to write answers. As for specifying, I just want to underline that if one can use Overloading, then he/she shouldn't use Specifying.

Comment: @Constructor how can you be too lazy? Just type the same text in a different field. And i am still puzzled what "specifiying a function" is supposed to mean

Comment: @user463035818 Well, I think a high quality answer should have code-given. And i'm using cellphone now, so i don't want to write code now. And it seems my bad English accounts for your puzzling? If i still cannot express it correctly, i'd like to only use "specify `get`" to express, sorry! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know, functions can not be overloaded by only return value types. I noticed that your types are default constructible thus I used them as function arguments with empty default values, so function can be overloaded by this default argument type: https://ideone.com/oPSWLC

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T get(const std::string &prompt, T ret = T()) {
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::cin >> ret;
    return ret;
}

std::string get(const std::string &prompt) {
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::string ret;
    std::getline(std::cin, ret);
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    get<int>("int: ");
    get<std::string>("string: ");
}
```

---

Template specialization for the string returning function is not needed, an exactly matched overloaded function is of higher priority than the function template.

Comment: T ret = T() what is this supposed to mean?
And the 2nd function breaks some things I know about functions. Shouldn't I have 2 parameters when I call the string return function? and why do you use "template<>" anymore?

Comment: I've updated the answer to avoid two your questions.

Comment: Hey, are you alive :D ? Had a break from C++, came back, why is this not working anymore?

Comment: @SKREFI Please [Ask Your Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)